How to progress smoothly LinearProgressIndicator
So I'm trying to create a linear progress indicator in Flutter, that over 5 seconds, smoothly fill in the indicator. Currently my approach is the following:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFile> createState() => _MyFileState();
}

class _MyFileState extends State<MyFile> {
  double _value = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        _value += .2;
      });

      if (_value == 1) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
          value: _value,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This works but the progress is shown in steps rather than smoothly filling the progress indicator. Is there any way I can accomplish that? Thank you

use TweenAnimation builder .It will take start and end value .For more detauils check this video https://youtu.be/l9uHB8VXZOg

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html

To create a smooth LinearProgressIndicator gradually fills over a period of time, you can use the

AnimationController
and
TweenAnimationBuilder

for more precise and smooth animation.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFile> createState() => _MyFileState();
}

class _MyFileState extends State<MyFile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize the AnimationController
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5), // total duration for the progress
    )..forward(); // start the animation immediately
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose(); // Always dispose of the controller when not needed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: _controller.value, // This value changes smoothly over time
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


AnimationController

: We use this to control the animation. It smoothly changes its value from 0.0 to 1.0 over a period of time, which you specify (in this case, 5 seconds).

forward()

: This starts the animation immediately after the controller is created.

AnimatedBuilder

: This widget rebuilds the LinearProgressIndicator whenever the animation's value changes, providing a smooth transition.

dispose()

: We make sure to dispose of the AnimationController when it's no longer needed to prevent memory leaks.
